# "this.innerHTML" returns "undefined" while inspecting "this" DOM properties shows a content

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

I found a lot of (partly) similar posts on SO, but they all involve pretty obvious errors, generally because the given `this` is not what they believe at the time they ask for `this.innerHTML`.

But here I face a situation where execution is paused (with Firefox debugger) on a breakpoint on the statement involving `this.innerHTML`, and simultaneously:

- striking `this.innerHTML` in the console returns `undefined`
- but the `this` DOM properties shows `innerHTML: "...some text..."

The latter matches what I'd expect, since the current `this` is a simple element `<span class="summary">...some text...</span>`.
So I wonder how `this.innerHTML` can return `undefined` here.

Another way to illustrate the contradiction, compare these two responses from the console:

- `this.innerHTML` -> `undefined`
- `$(this)[0].innerHTML` -> `"...some text..."`

I hope I'm simply (and dumbly) missing something obvious.

---

EDIT: I tried to present an excerpt of the involved code.

Here is the schematized most interesting part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ...some stuff
  $('html').each(renderElement); // <-- here is the main call
  // ...some stuff
}

function renderElement() { // <-- the involved function
  if (this.innerHTML.match(/^\s*\[multi\]/)) { // <-- the this.innerHTML point
    this.innerHTML = renderString(this.innerHTML);
    return;
  }

  // Otherwise recursively explore each node
  $(this).contents().each(function() {
    switch (this.nodeType) {
      case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        // ...some stuff
        break;
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        // ...some stuff
        renderElement.call(this); // <-- here is the alternate (recursive) call
        break;
      default:
        // Do nothing for any other nodeType.
    }
  });
}
```

NOTE: when the issue happens, necessarily the `renderElement` function has been called through the alternate call (since the involved `<span>` is not part of the 1st level elements).

Comment: @KobyDouek Hmmm... strange suggestion, but I just tried it: returns the same, as expected since AFAIK `innerHtml` doesn't exist.

Comment: Does it happen only on FireFox? What happens on Chrome dev console?

Comment: Hard to say without code, if the scope is the same, `$(this)[0].innerHTML` and `this.innerHTML` should really return the same and do on my machine! Can you add a snippet?

Comment: `$(this)[0].innerHTML` if this works , then $(this) is an array of node element

Comment: Can you show us how you got "this"?  Is it in an event-handler?  What does `console.log(this)` give you?

Comment: @Durga I don't really understand what you mean: sure `$(this) is an array of node element` but... so what?

Comment: @HarryPehkonen `console.log(this)` returns `Object [ <span.summary> ]`, like simple `this` in the console does.

Comment: Your question is going to be difficult to answer because you haven't provided code/context.

Comment: @HarryPehkonen In response to another part of your comment: it's in a `renderElement` function called by `$('html').each(renderElement)`. Also the `renderElement` recursively explores nodes when they are ELEMENT_NODE: so you see that the involved `this.innerHTML` occurs _a lot_ of times... and works fine for all cases, except the one I'm pointing here!

Comment: @Andy (and @ Joschi) It's pretty hard to imagine how to give really comprehensive code without a lot of code! Look at my previous comment to @ HarryPehkonen. In the other hand, isn'it enough to have the current data with its contradictory content?

Comment: If we can't reproduce the problem how can we understand what the context of the problem is? Maybe start by adding the `renderElement` function to your question, with some example HTML, or add it as a JS fiddle or something.

Comment: @Andy Please look at my edit! TIA

Comment: @Joschi Please look at my edit! TIA

Comment: @HarryPehkonen Please look at my edit! TIA

Comment: @KobyDouek Please look at my edit! TIA

Comment: @Durga Please look at my edit! TIA

Comment: @cFreed Can you add some HTML above to make the script above actually do something meaningful? Ideally, it would be some HTML and script which, when combined, are able to reproduce the issue you're describing.

Comment: @JLRishe To present some illustrating HTML is very difficult, because the issue happens inside a Drupal module which is intended to work upon _any_ HTML content: it explores it recursively, looking for a specific pattern in TEXT_NODE nodes, then changing the node content depending on that pattern. Anyway __your comment make me solve the issue__, because it lead me to explore the current case deeply and discover a rather bent situation where `this` is not the DOM element but a jQuery-like object holding the DOM element! Too complex for explaining it here: I'll do it in a own answer. __Thanks!__